# Visual Studio 2017, Windows Form Application; How to Display an Error Message

Tags: vb.net

[This is the code I have at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXF0F.png) So I am doing a simple project from our textbook in my Visual Basic class.  We are using inputted numbers from text boxes to input into an equation.  I would highly impress my instructor if I could display an error message for if/when she puts in a letter rather than a number.  I have tried multiple ways but I cannot figure it out.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Next time you ask for help, It is useful if you show the code you have tried so people on here can see where the error is on the code and can help you understand why that is happening.

Comment: Users on here are picky on how the code is shown. What you need to do is copy your code and paste it in as a code block by making sure there are at least 4 spaces at the beginning of each code line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question you would doing a try catch statement.

```
Try
    'code here
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("There was an error. Try entering a number")
End Try
```

Comment: How would I tell that to run though? That is my main issue.  Thanks

Comment: This video might be about to explain it  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS-7wjoXvAE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS-7wjoXvAE)

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.  I'm sure that's a simple way to do it but I never would have figured it out.